# How to set up cross-referencing between UIViews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

First q here, so trying to get protocol right...what I've done works, in that the data and views display correctly, but memory is not deallocating (still getting used to ARC after many years of allocating/deallocating), and I'm trying to figure out the right strategy. Document based app. When doc is created, view controller is instantiated, which creates several views which need to refer to each other for size/position/methods, and all of which need access to the doc data.

```
class MyDoc: UIDocument {
var data: Int
etc...
}

class MyController: UIViewController {
var doc: myDoc! // code which creates MyDoc instance assigns self to this property
var thisView1: MyView1!
var thisView2: MyView2!
thisView1 = MyView1(...)
thisView2 = MyView2(...)
thisView1.theOtherView2 = thisView2
thisView2.theOtherView1 = thisView1
thisView1.doc = self.doc
thisView2.doc = self.doc
}

class MyView1: UIView {
var theOtherView2: MyView2!
var doc: MyDoc!
}

class MyView2: UIView {
var theOtherView1: MyView1!
var doc: MyDoc!
}
```

I don't think I excluded anything meaningful. Assigning thisView1 and thisView2 to each other creates a strong reference cycle, right? I tried combining an unowned property on one with implicitly unwrapped on the other, per The Swift Programming Language, but kept having trouble with the init() methods of the views. Is using weak references and then unwrapping the optional all the time (though I make sure there's a valid value before proceeding from viewController) the only thing that'll work? I've read so many explanations that each new one now confuses me more.

Thank you!

Comment: You are right, using `weak` keyword can avoid the strong reference cycle here.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Bit the bullet, converted to weak, seeing classes deinit at least enough to track down other ref cycles. Thanks Eric.